# How can I arrange a dictionary using python so that the values are represented from lowest to highest order?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value, items

I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'A': {'A1': 2, 'A4': 4, 'A5': 1}, 'B': {'B3': 1, 'B7': 8, 'B5': 2}}
```

How can I rearrange the dictionary to organize the values from lowest to highest order?
I am expecting to have the  following output after rearranging the dictionary based on the values:

```
d = {'A': {'A5': 1, 'A1': 2, 'A4': 4}, 'B': {'B3': 1, 'B5': 2, 'B7': 8,}}
```

I tried to use the sorted option, `d = sorted(d.items())`, but it sorts the dictionary based on the keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: I did try the following: d = {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}, but it doesn't work. I get a TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {'A': {'A1': 2, 'A4': 4, 'A5': 1}, 'B': {'B3': 1, 'B7': 8, 'B5': 2}}
sorted_dict = {i:dict(sorted(d[i].items(),key=lambda x:x[1])) for i in d.keys()}
```

I know that it's pretty hard to read, so I will try to explain what I can.
Basically, you are using the sorted function which takes an iterable and a function of one argument which tells the sorted function to sort the iterable on the basis of that lambda function.

Edit:
I forgot to show the output.

```
{'A': {'A5': 1, 'A1': 2, 'A4': 4}, 'B': {'B3': 1, 'B5': 2, 'B7': 8}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from your comment was on the right direction, you just need to sort the inner `dict`s with a loop and not the outer `dict`

```
d = {k: dict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])) for k, v in d.items()}
```

after that you can also sort the outer dictionary if needed

```
d = dict(sorted(d.items()))
```

Everything in a single dict-comprehension

```
d = {k: dict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])) for k, v in sorted(d.items())}
```